# How to get auto populate a list of data in drop down list using columnFilter Plugin

Tags: c#, jquery, drop-down-menu, filtering, datatables

I am using columnFilter Plugin for jQuery DataTables and everything works fine apart from getting the custom filters `select` to work so they auto populate from the data. The [documentation](http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/customFilters.html) displays that, is all needed to specify the values. i.e. `{ type: "select" }` but it doesn't work and just shows the column name in the drop-down list but no data.

[Screen Shot](http://s12.postimg.org/jqfnir9bh/Untitled_1.png) - The `drop-down` is not showing a list of Tracks from the table.

**Here's the columnFilter code for your inspection:**

```
$('#myDataTable').dataTable().columnFilter({
            aoColumns: [
                null,
                { sSelector: "#dateselectorFilter", type: "date-range" },
                { sSelector: "#trackselectorFilter",  type: "select" },
                null,
                null
            ]
        }
        );
});
```

`type: "select"` should pull all the values in the `drop-down` list.

**C# Controller Code: Do i need to define a list here? i.e. `.ToList()` If so then how Can I do that?**

```
filteredTracks = filteredTracks.Where(c => (trackFilter == "" || c.TrackName.ToLower().Contains(trackFilter.ToLower()))
```

**Here's full jQuery dataTable code I have:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.datepicker.regional[""].dateFormat = 'dd/mm/yy';
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional[''])

    $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search Tracks: ",
        },
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "AjaxHandler",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sScrollY": "150",
        "bFilter": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bRetrieve": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength": 150,
        "aoColumns": [
    { "mData": "TrackID" },
    {
        "mData": "Date", "bSortable": false,
        "fnRender": function (obj, val) {
            var dx = new Date(parseInt(val.substr(6)));
            var dd = dx.getDate();
            var mm = dx.getMonth() + 1;
            var yy = dx.getFullYear();

            if (dd <= 9) {
                dd = "0" + dd;
            }
            if (mm <= 9) {
                mm = "0" + mm;
            }
            return dd + " / " + mm + " / " + yy;
        }
    },
    { "mData": "TrackName" },
    { "mData": "ArtistName" },
    { "mData": "Times" }
        ]
    });



    $('#myDataTable').dataTable().columnFilter({
            aoColumns: [
                null,
                { sSelector: "#dateselectorFilter", mData: "Date", type: "date-range" },
                { sSelector: "#trackselectorFilter",  type: "select" },
                null,
                null
            ]
        }
        );
});
```

Any help would be great :) Thanks

Comment: Well can you show me your code that you are calling to pull data into dropdownlist . The given c# code is in which way it is related to dropdwon . . Add code

Comment: @supercool sorry about that.. That is the particular line that does the filtering but not auto populating the data. Hence, I was thinking to add `.ToList()` to the line but it gives me errors. I have updated by full controller for your inspection :) thanks in advance

Comment: well pretty straight farowrd one may be . can you mention me the convertion issue you are facing  . still i am amazed how this convertion is related to dropdwon and column filter . Cheers . The ajaxhandler doesnt not come into picture to populate data in dropdown . you have to do seperatly .

Comment: thanks for this :).. you're right the controller doesn't populate the data to drop-down list, it only does the normal filtering. Let me try and do what you suggested, to do the population of the data separately :) thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can find this link which is capable of solving every issue 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part

**Coming to you question asked :**

**First** : You can apply ToList just becoz you are stroing it in ienumarable so it wont be any issue only if there is a mismatch in the inside like 
`list<mode1> and ienumarable<model2>` .
Make sure both models are same

**Second** : To populate list in dropdwon you have to make a seperate call :

```
{
                    indicator: 'Saving...',
                    tooltip: 'Click to select town',
                    loadtext: 'loading...',
                    type: 'select',
                    onblur: 'submit',
                    loadurl: 'AjaxDataProvider1'
}
```

Cheers

Comment: thanks for the answer, makes more sense now :) let me give it a try as to what you suggested. Could you please provide some help with the `.Tolist()`? if it's ok and thanks once again for your help :)

Comment: sure mate but u need to provide me the error info what you are getting .

Comment: thanks :) I am trying to add `.ToList()` to this line `filteredTracks = filteredTracks
                .Where(c => (trackFilter == "" || c.TrackName.ToLower().ToList().Contains(trackFilter.ToLower()))` but I get this error `cannot convert from string to char & List<char> has invalid arguments`. thanks once again :)

Comment: oh common dude you cant do like that . just try like this if you are really interested to do so . keep ToList at end . `filteredTracks = filteredTracks.Where(c => (trackFilter == "" || c.TrackName.ToLower().Contains(trackFilter.ToLower())).ToList();` mark it as answer if it helps . cheers

Comment: reason is pretty st.farword its expecting a char you are passing string or whatever . . To test try passing 'c' . cheers